# Combine date and time when date is a DateTime and time is a string

Tags: c#, datetime

I am working with an old mysql database in which a date is stored (without a time) as a datetime and a time is stored as a string (without a date).

In C# I then have a DateTime with a value like `2010-06-25 12:00:00 AM` and a String with a value like `15:02`.

What is the most concise way to combine these without a lot of overhead?

I have tried a few methods including:

```
DateTime NewDateTime = DateTime.Parse(OldDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd ") + TimeString);
```

I dislike converting the existing DateTime to a string and appending the time.

I can convert the time string to a date, but then I get today's date and adding it as a number of ticks to the old datetime is incorrect.

*Note: Don't worry about validation, it is done elsewhere. The time is represented using 24-hour format without seconds.*

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use [TimeSpan.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx) to parse the time, and then add the result to the date:

```
DateTime newDateTime = oldDateTime.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(timeString));
```

Comment: good solution. @JYelton, I'd use this and mark dtb's answer correct.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about using `TimeSpan` - this is precisely what was needed.

Answer (score 12):

```
var dt = new DateTime(2010, 06, 26); // time is zero by default
var tm = TimeSpan.Parse("01:16:50");
var fullDt = dt + tm; // 2010-06-26 01:16:50
```

Answer (score 6):

I used something similar to what simendsjo says, except I continued to have it as a DateTime

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTrainDate.Text);
DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(ddTrainTime.SelectedValue);
DateTime dtCOMPLTDTTM = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second);
```

Comment: Good for when you want to combine the "time" part of one `DateTime` value and the "date" part of another `DateTime` value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're worrying about the string conversion too much. By combining the 2 string elements together you are saving further date string parsing anyway which will most likely be more expensive.

Is this going to be repeated a lot of times or a simple step in a larger process?

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure you could combine and convert these values into a timestamp using SQL.

Comment: Hitting the database for such things is a really bad idea. Your program will be a lot slower, and suddenly have strong external dependencies without any good reason.