# how to concat date and time in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Higuys,

I have a Textbox where user choose **a date** (MM/dd/yyyy) and another TextBox where choose inserts **time** (hh:mm).

```
<tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="cp_title">Event Date:</asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="cp_title">Event Time(hh:mm):</asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEventDate" runat="server">
                </asp:TextBox>
                <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="cldEventDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEventDate"
                    PopupPosition="BottomLeft" Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
                </cc1:CalendarExtender>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEventTime"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

In the database I have a **single column for DateTime** so I have to "concatenate" the user input into a real datetime format...

I see a constructor for DateTime which takes as args: *year, month, day, hour, minute, second,* but this requires me to parse user input and split in these periods....

Do you know an easier solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine date and time when date is a DateTime and time is a string.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122015/combine-date-and-time-when-date-is-a-datetime-and-time-is-a-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(txtEventDate.Text + " " + txtEventTime.Text,
                    "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: What does CultureInfo.InvariantCulture mean?

Answer (score 6):

You should probably validate and/or trim the text from the textboxes before attempting any kind of concatenation.

```
    string _eventDate = "01/01/2011";  //in your case txtEventDate.Text
    string _eventTime = "09:00 AM"; //in your case txtEventTime.Text

    DateTime eventDate = Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("{0} {1}",(_eventDate), _eventTime)));
```

I would strongly suggest using JqueryUI to provide you with Date and Time pickers.
Demos:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/

Answer (score 2):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) method.

```
string dateString = txtEventDate.Text + " " + txtEventTime.Text;
string format = dateFormat + " " + timeFormat;  
DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
string date = "1/2/2011";
string time = "12:15";
DateTime temp = Convert.ToDateTime(date + " " + time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method with an appropiate format string and your concattenated user input.